# matrix list comprehension mean

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

This is an offshoot of a previous question which started to snowball.  If I have a matrix A and I want to use the mean/average of each row [1:] values to create another matrix B, but keep the row headings intact, how would I do this?  I've included matrix A, my attempt at cobbling together a list comprehension, and the expected result.

```
from operator import sum,len

# matrix A with row headings and values
A = [('Apple',0.95,0.99,0.89,0.87,0.93),
('Bear',0.33,0.25.0.85,0.44,0.33),
('Crab',0.55,0.55,0.10,0.43,0.22)]

#List Comprehension
B = [(A[0],sum,A[1:]/len,A[1:]) for A in A]
```

Expected outcome

```
B = [('Apple', 0.926), ('Bear', 0.44), ('Crab', 0.37)]
```

Comment: One of these things is not like the others.  Why isn't this data in a dictionary?  `{'APPLE':(0.95,0.99,0.89,0.87,0.93), ... }`

Comment: `(A[0],sum,A[1:]/len,A[1:])` should read `(A[0],sum(A[1:])/len(A[1:]))`. `sum` and `len` are functions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your list comprehension looks a little weird.  You are using the same variable for the iterable and the item.

This approach seems to work:

```
def average(lst):
    return sum(lst) / len(lst)

B = [(a[0], average(a[1:])) for a in A]
```

I've created a function `average` for readability.  It matches your expected values, so I think that's what you want, although your use of `mul` suggests that I may be missing something.

Comment: Is there no way to simply embed the average function in the comprehension code itself without worrying about definitions?  It seems that would be simpler.  My use of mul was a mistake, I meant sum.

Comment: I do appreciate your solution, but I'm a simple guy.

Comment: @Jeff: *Not* including the `average()` calculation in the list comprehension *is* simple.

Comment: @Jeff: I do believe this is simpler, as it's easier to understand, but I'm sure you can figure out how to inline it.

Comment: I guess so.  I'm still new to all this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Taking from @recursive and @Steven Rumbalski:

```
>>> def average(lst):
...     return sum(lst) / len(lst)
... 
>>> A = {
...     'Apple': (0.95, 0.99, 0.89, 0.87, 0.93),
...     'Bear': (0.33, 0.25, 0.85, 0.44, 0.33),
...     'Crab': (0.55, 0.55, 0.10, 0.43, 0.22),
... }
>>> 
>>> B = [{key: average(values)} for key, values in A.iteritems()]
>>> B
[{'Apple': 0.92599999999999993}, {'Bear': 0.44000000000000006}, {'Crab': 0.37}]
```